# Filtering array of objects by object key

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to filter array of objects by key?

```
const users = [{
  forename: "Arlene",
  isActive: true,
  isManager: false,
  language: "fr",
  partnerNumber: "92250507",
}, {
  ...
}]
```

Should be filtered by array of keys

```
const keys = ['forename', 'isActive'];
```

Expected result is:

```
const filteredUsers = [{
  forename: "Arlene",
  isActive: true,

}, {
  ...
}, {
  ...
}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you want us to code for you. Please share if you have tried anything

Comment: Hello, my name is the [`array.map(fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, I take an array as input and returns a new array altered after the `fn` function has been applied on each element.

Comment: You absolutely right!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` like the following. The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const users = [{
    forename: "Arlene",
    isActive: true,
    isManager: false,
    language: "fr",
    partnerNumber: "92252107",
  },
  {
    forename: "Chris",
    isActive: false,
    isManager: false,
    language: "en",
    partnerNumber: "92250507",
  }
]

let filteredList = users.map(item => {
  return {
    forename: item.forename,
    isActive: item.isActive
  }
});

console.log(filteredList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```js
const users = [{
  forename: "Arlene",
  isActive: true,
  isManager: false,
  language: "fr",
  partnerNumber: "92250507",
}, {
  forename: "Arlene2",
  isActive: true,
  isManager: false,
  language: "fr",
  partnerNumber: "92250507",
}]

const keys = ["forename", "isActive"];

const filteredUsers = users.map(user => {
  let u = {};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    u[key] = user[key];
  });
  return u;
});

console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Comment: Why using an array to store keys ? That does not make sense unless you create a function that takes a list of keys to filter.

Answer (score 0):

The way you put your question seems you just want to `map` it as in change your array elements into a different format.

If you want to `filter` to get just the active ones (`isActive`?) then yes you should use a `filter` also.

I'm assuming your keys are just hardcoded so there's not really a need for it. And with this we can just create our mapper function and use some deconstruction for simplicity

```js
const users = [{
    forename: "Arlene",
    isActive: true,
    isManager: false,
    language: "fr",
    partnerNumber: "92252107",
  },
  {
    forename: "Chris",
    isActive: false,
    isManager: false,
    language: "en",
    partnerNumber: "92250507",
  }
]

const mapUser = ({ forename, isActive }) => ({ forename, isActive });
let filteredList = users.map(mapUser);

console.log(filteredList)
```

Answer (score -2):

@Paul has given a good answer.. you might also use the "filter" array helper.. instead of map help like this.

```
  const users = [{
  forename: "Arlene",
  isActive: true,
  isManager: false,
  language: "fr",
  partnerNumber: "92250507",
}, {
  forename: "Arlene2",
  isActive: true,
  isManager: false,
  language: "fr",
  partnerNumber: "92250507",
}]

var filteredList = users.filter(function(user) {
    return {forename: user.forename, isActive: true};
});
filteredList;
```

Comment: your are returning the same array after filtering because `{forename: user.forename, isActive: true}` is truthy...